# Pulling Win10 activation codes from remote computers

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm brand new to PS scripting, so bear with me :)

I'm trying to create a PS script that will write the Win10 activation code to a file then copy that file to a central repo to then manually activate.

I'm creating a PS script and trying to run

```
cscript.exe c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs -dti > 
$SourceDir\$env:computername.txt 
$SourceDir = \\computer01\c$\temp
```

I need to run it from one computer, remotely connecting to every computer on the network, creating the computername.txt file then copying that file back to a central repository for all the files.

What I have so far:

---

```
$s1=New-PSSession -ComputerName computer01 -Credential $AdminCred
Test-Connection -ComputerName computer01
$id='\\computer01\windows\system32'
$SourceDir='\\computer01\c$\temp'
md $SourceDir
$GetActID=cscript.exe $id\slmgr.vbs -dti > 
$SourceDir\$env:computername.txt
Invoke-Command -Session $s1 -ScriptBlock { $Using:GetActID }
```

---

Then I call a batch file that copies the computername.txt file from the computer01 over to a repository where they are going to sit.

I FINALLY got it working correctly except for the name of the file isn't naming it to the computer01, it's naming it with the hostname of the computer I'm running it from, therefore the filenames are identical.  I had the naming piece working, but I had to change the way I was remoting into the computer and now it's not naming correctly.

Any idea on how I could get it to name the file to be related to the remote computer?

**I'm still working on the whole piece of the puzzle where it goes back to an excel sheet pulled from AD and pulls the host names from that sheet to connect to each machine, I believe I'll be adding a ForEach syntax in there somehow for that.

Comment: Hey Theo, I did comment below, although that suggestion will likely work in most cases, it won't work for me with the restrictions I have to work within.

Comment: Ow, sorry.. forgot about that.. Really a pity you are restricted that much and have to work around it.

Comment: Yeah it is a very restricted environment, makes for some very creative solutions such as this one, it sounds really convoluted and really it is but the restrictions have created my need for learning scripting.  Your help below is greatly appreciated, it made sense of a few things for me.  Thanks Theo.

Answer (score 0):

Although not sure how you are getting the list of *"every computer on the network"*, chances are you are doing this using

```
# get a list of all AD computers (their names only)
$computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name
```

Then I think you don't need to have every computer save the file on its own disk and later copy these files to a central share.
Instead, just capture the info in a variable and after the loop write the file to the central share as structured CSV file combining all computernames and install id's so you can open in Excel.

Using the array of computernames from above, iterate through them

```
$result = $computers | ForEach-Object {
    # test if the computer can be reached
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        $installId = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock { 
            cscript.exe //nologo "$env:SystemRoot\System32\slmgr.vbs" -dti 
        }
        # $installId is returned as array !
        # output an object with two properties
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Computer  = $_
            InstallId = $installId[0] -replace '\D'  # remove everything non-numeric
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Computer $_ is not responding"
    }
}

# now you can display the result on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# or by means of the GridView if you prefer
$result | Out-GridView -Title 'Computer InstallIds'

# and save the results in your central share as structured CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path '\\server\share\restofpath\ComputerInstallIds.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>You may have to append `-Credential $adminCreds` to the `Invoke-Command` call to make sure you have permissions to have each machine run that piece of code in the scriptblock. The easiest way of obtaining that credential is to start off with `$adminCreds = Get-Credential -Message "Please enter administrator credentials"`</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately with the restrictions that I'm required to work within, your suggestion works great in most cases but I'm unable to do deploy this solution (it's great info though so thank you).